# Prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. Suppose that there is a constant $B$ such that $\left| f^ı\left( x\right) \right| \leq B$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Can you give a hint?

Comment: @projectilemotion I tried mean value theorem.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $\vert f'(x) \vert \leq B$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ implies that
$$\left\vert \frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y} \right\vert \leq B$$
for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Can we use mean value theorem?

Comment: The mean value theorem tells you that the hint is true.

Comment: By the mean value theorem, we find $\left| f(x)-f(y)\right| \leq B \left| x-y\right|$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. So, how can I show that this is uniformly continuous?

Comment: The answer is staring you in the face. Choose $\epsilon > 0$. Then
$$B\vert x - y \vert < \epsilon$$
if $\vert x - y \vert < $...